# Send parameters from directive to controllers in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

Inside `oferta-ut.controller.js` I need to change state from `main.ut.ofertas` to `main.ut.resumen`. Then select something and call `scope.clickAction` inside `ut-result.directive.js`. This action should send parameters to `oferta-ut.controller.js` so I can use it with others parameters to go to another state.

Here goes some code

### servicio-ut.controller.js

```
$state.go('main.ut.ofertas', {
    plan: $stateParams.plan,
    destino: $stateParams.destino,
    fechaEntrada: $stateParams.fechaEntrada,
    fechaSalida: $stateParams.fechaSalida,
    duracion: $stateParams.duracion,
    huespedes: $stateParams.huespedes,
    servicio: ctrl.servicioInc,
});
```

### oferta-ut.controller.js

```
'use strict';

function ofertasUtCtrl($scope, $stateParams, $state, 
  unidadTuristicaService, moment, util, SessionService, $analytics, $window) {
  'ngInject';
  var ctrl = this,

  if (!$stateParams.servicio) {
    $state.go('main.home');
  } else {
    ctrl.ofertaSeleccionada=null;
    activate();
  }

  function activate() {

    var fechaEntrada = $stateParams.fechaEntrada.getFullYear() + "-" +
     ($stateParams.fechaEntrada.getMonth() + 1) + "-" +
     $stateParams.fechaEntrada.getDate();

    var fechaSalida = $stateParams.fechaSalida.getFullYear() + "-" +
     ($stateParams.fechaSalida.getMonth() + 1)  + "-" +
     $stateParams.fechaSalida.getDate();     

    unidadTuristicaService.obtenerOfertasUt(
        $stateParams.plan.id,$stateParams.servicio.code,
        $stateParams.destino.id,
        fechaEntrada,
        fechaSalida,
        $stateParams.duracion.id)
    .then(function(ofertas){
      for(var clave in ofertas.resultadoBusquedaUt){
        ofertas.resultadoBusquedaUt[clave].fechaDesde = moment(fechaEntrada).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
        ofertas.resultadoBusquedaUt[clave].fechaHasta = moment(fechaSalida).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
      }
      ctrl.ofertas = ofertas;
    });    
  } 

  ctrl.confirmarServ = function() {
      $analytics.eventTrack("Clic Siguiente", {
          category: 'UT',
          label: "Clic Servicios UT"
      });

      $state.go('main.ut.resumen', {
        plan: $stateParams.plan,
        destino: $stateParams.destino,
        fechaEntrada: ctrl.fechaEntrada,
        fechaSalida: ctrl.fechaSalida,
        huespedes: ctrl.cantHuespuedes,
        duracion: $stateParams.duracion,
        servicio: ctrl.servicioInc
      });       
  };
}

module.exports = ofertasUtCtrl;
```

The view for the action is this one

```
<div flex>    
    <pager results="ctrl.ofertas.resultadoBusquedaUt" per-page="10" result-type="UT"></pager>
</div>
```

### ut-result.directive.js

```
"use strict";

var utResultView = require('./ut-result.view.html'),
  imgPlaceHolder = require('../../img/hotel_holder.png');

function hotelResult(util, $state, moment) {
  'ngInject';
  var directive = {
      templateUrl: utResultView,
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        model: '=',
        params: '<'
      },
      link: link
  };
  return directive;

  function link(scope) {
    scope.icono = mapearIcono;

    scope.filterHide = function() {
      // ver si está filtrado por algun criterio
      return scope.model.filterHide && scope.model.filterHide.length > 0;
    };

    var unbindWatch = scope.$watch("model", function(oldV, newV) {
      if (newV) {
        activate();
      }
    });

    function activate() {
      // iterador para estrellitas
      scope.estrellas = [1,2,3,4,5].slice(0, scope.model.estrellas);
      //Categoria UT
      scope.categoriaUt = scope.model.categoriasUt;
      scope.datosPrestador = scope.model.razonSocial + ' - CUIT: '  + scope.model.cuit;

      scope.imgSrc = scope.model.urlImagen || imgPlaceHolder;
      scope.imgError = imgPlaceHolder;
      scope.precio = scope.model.precio? util.formatCurrency(scope.model.precio) : null;

      scope.clickAction = function(model) {
        // THIS ACTION
      };
  }
}

module.exports = hotelResult;
```

Comment: The signature of the listener function in the `$watch` method should be `function(newVal, oldVal`, not as done in the question.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice, but I'm not sure the problem comes from there. but anyway i will do the change.